# Laravel L5.5 dynamic request validation that depends on variable

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

In my controller, I have something like that:

```
switch ($type)
    {
        case '1':
            $validation_rules = [
                'a' => 'required',
                'b' => 'required',];
            break;
        case '2':
            $validation_rules = [
                'd' => 'required',
                'j' => 'nullable|numeric',];
            break;
        case '3':
            $validation_rules = [
                't1.x' => 'required|numeric',
                't1.y' => 'required|numeric',];
            break;
    }

$request->validate($validation_rules);
```

But I dont like this because it mass up my controller. 
I am looking for a way to use request validation instead.

Something like that would be my target:

```
public function store(XXRequest $request)
```

And put the logic for the validation inside.

Comment: how you get the value of $type in your controller??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new request file:

```
php artisan make:request SomeRequest
```

Put the logic into the `rules()` method:

```
public function rules()
{
    switch ($this->type)
        {
            case '1':
                $validation_rules = [
                    'a' => 'required',
                    'b' => 'required',];
                break;
            case '2':
                $validation_rules = [
                    'd' => 'required',
                    'j' => 'nullable|numeric',];
                break;
            case '3':
                $validation_rules = [
                    't1.x' => 'required|numeric',
                    't1.y' => 'required|numeric',];
                break;
        }

    return $validation_rules;
}
```

Then use it:

```
public function store(SomeRequest $request)
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: Thank you, but how can I pass the $type variable to rules() ?

Comment: @titonior if it's a get parameter or a form element, you can use `request()` helper as I've shown in the updated answer.

Comment: this is exactly the answer I was looking for. It is obviously somehow, but I was not thinking about it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use $this->type

Comment: @dobs edited. It's a good idea to use `$this->type` inside in this case. Thank you.